# Sweave breaking on escape characters?

Tags: r, texworks, sweave

I'm attempting to build out a pdf using texworks and sweave. I can get an output just fine except for a certain chunk of code and I can't tell why.

Here's an example of it working:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\title{Cross-Validation by Example }
\usepackage{Sweave}
\begin{document}
\maketitle

\begin{Schunk}
\begin{Sinput}
> train <- train[,8:length(colnames(train))]
> test <- test[,8:length(colnames(test))]
> nonNAs <- function(x) {
+   as.vector(apply(x, 2, function(x) length(which(!is.na(x)))))
+ }
> colnames_train <- colnames(train)
> colcnts <- nonNAs(train)
> drops <- c()
> for (cnt in 1:length(colcnts)) {
+   if (colcnts[cnt] < nrow(train)) {
+     drops <- c(drops, colnames_train[cnt])
+   }
+ }
> train <- train[,!names(train) \%in\% drops]
> test <- test[,!names(test) \%in\% drops]
\end{Sinput}
\end{Schunk}

\end{document}
```

That file runs without issue and has plenty of R code in it. I had to make sure the % signs weren't active as comments, so I explicitly put a backlash in before them. However, the seemingly simpler code below throws an exception:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\title{Cross-Validation by Example }
\usepackage{Sweave}
\begin{document}
\maketitle

\begin{Schunk}
\begin{Sinput}
 > set.seed(123)
 > cv <- train(cut_train1$classe ~ ., method="rf", trControl=trainControl(method="cv", number = 4), data=cut_train1)
 > print(cv, digits=3)
\end{Sinput}
\begin{Soutput}

\end{document}
```

The console output tells me this at the bottom:

```
LaTeX Warning: No \author given.

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\ae\t1aett.fd"))
Runaway argument?
! File ended while scanning use of \FancyVerbGetLine.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
<*> ...ocs/dev/blog/book/outline/sweaveML/pml3.tex

?
```

Am I missing something obvious? Is it the tilde that is breaking the escape character rule?

Answer (score 0):

Ok I think I found the answer. The file's name was pml3.tex. I had run `Sweave()` on a file named "pml.Rnw" which gave me my original doc of pml.tex. Running the code in that original document worked just fine. I imagine it's because Sweave has to link up to the pml.synctex file and the pml3.tex file was not pointing to it.